# google app engine in cygwin

Tags: google-app-engine, cygwin

I am trying to install google app engine in cygwin. I know I need to install python 2.7 to run. This is because with 3.0 I had some problems. But 2.7.3 doesn't exist in the cygwin installation package. I can install it in windows, but cannot access it from cygwin. Does someone know the proper way to run Google App Engine in windows using Cygwin?

Comment: Why running it on windows under Cygwin?

Comment: the course I take has the examples shown in linux. Since I have windows, It seems a fair compromise to try. if it is possible of course.

Comment: You can run GAE through windows.. and everything else do it using Cygwin.. just install the Launcher..

Comment: Cygwin now has python 2.7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried running GAE in cygwin.  Mostly because I ran other tools like git in cygwin.

The proper way is to run GAE outside of cygwin and follow the windows instructions on the GAE downloads page.

If you need a linux environment, run linux in a VM.  It'll be much less painful than cygwin.  You'll run into many other issues with cygwin where certain tools like git work 95% of the time but have frustrating bugs the other 5%.

Comment: thanks @dragonx. I tried a lot of things, so now I will stop efforts on Cygwin.